# Describe the distribution of a random variable - measure and integration theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm currently working on exercises in measure and integration theory. The exercise:

"**Exercise 2.22:** Consider a random experiment consisting of throwing a fair die twice. Describe the probability space corresponding to this experiment. Then consider a random variable on this space which to each event associates the difference between the two throws (i.e, the number of points of the first throw minus the number of points of the second throw). Describe the distribution of this random variable."

So I am supposed to describe the random variable. I might know how to describe it, but it's long time since I've worked with probability theory, so if I could get hints to get started with this exercise, then it would be really cool.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As outcome space you can take $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$.

As $\sigma$-algebra you can take $\wp(\Omega)$ so that every function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is measurable hence is a random variable.

As probability measure you can take $P:\wp(\Omega)\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $A\mapsto|A|/|\Omega|$ (corresponding with equiprobability of all outcomes).

Let $X_1:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $(i,j)\mapsto i$ (corresponding with the first throw).

Let $X_2:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $(i,j)\mapsto j$ (corresponding with the second throw).

---

You are further asked to describe the distribution of random variable $X_1-X_2$.